# Removing Elements from an ArrayList in a Map

Tags: arraylist, treemap

I have a TreeMap> and I want to search and remove an object from each arraylist if it contains said object. So if it were TreeMap> I want to remove "text" from each ArrayList in the TreeMap. I tried using a Nested For Each loop but when I went to remove the value I got ConcurrentModificationException, then I tried using nested Iterators but got a NoSuchElementException. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove an element while iterating.So what you can do is at first check whether the element you are trying to delete exist.If exist then break from iteration and remove the element.And if not exist then you do not have to delete it.Even you can delete in the first place without checking then TreeMap.remove() will return null.Here is a previous thread for your help [How to remove and add elements to TreeMap while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637026/how-to-remove-and-add-elements-to-treemap-while-iterating)

Comment: How would I remove that element after breaking from the loop without going through a loop until I find that element?